# Getting Cast Exception while testing web service

Tags: java, web-services, wsdl

I'm new to Java Web services, and I'm stuck with this for the past 4 days. 
Here s the problem , I intend to create web services to be used by other applications.The requirement is that the web service has to return multiple records from a table, so I created a sample web service and here is the code

Interface

```
@WebService 
@SOAPBinding(style = Style.DOCUMENT)
public interface TestClassInt {

/**
 * @param args
 */

@WebMethod
SampleClass[] getCaseId (String country);
}
```

A custom class with two string objects

```
public class SampleClass {
protected String caseid;
protected String dummy;

public SampleClass(){
    super();
}
public SampleClass(String caseid,String dummy){
    this.caseid=caseid;
    this.dummy=dummy;
}
public String getDummy() {
    return dummy;
}

public void setDummy(String dummy) {
    this.dummy = dummy;
}

public String getCaseid() {
    return caseid;
}

public void setCaseid(String caseid) {
    this.caseid = caseid;
}
}
```

and here s the implementation

```
@WebService(endpointInterface = "com.org.ccb.test.TestClassInt")
public class TestClassImpl implements TestClassInt {

public SampleClass[] getCaseId(String country) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    System.out.println("Console " + country);
    SampleClass tempSc[] = new SampleClass[2];
    tempSc[0]=new SampleClass();
    tempSc[1]=new SampleClass();
    tempSc[0].setCaseid(country);
    tempSc[0].setDummy(country);
    tempSc[1].setCaseid(country);
    tempSc[1].setDummy(country);
    return tempSc;
}

}
```

The WSDL generated using JBoss Developer Studio is

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<wsdl:definitions name="TestClassImplService targetNamespace="http://test.ccb.org.com/" xmlns:wsdl="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/" xmlns:tns="http://test.ccb.org.com/" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/soap/">
<wsdl:types>
<xs:schema xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:tns="http://test.ccb.org.com/" targetNamespace="http://test.ccb.org.com/" version="1.0">
<xs:element name="getCaseId" type="tns:getCaseId"/>
<xs:element name="getCaseIdResponse" type="tns:getCaseIdResponse"/>
<xs:complexType name="getCaseId">
<xs:sequence>
<xs:element minOccurs="0" name="arg0" type="xs:string"/>
</xs:sequence>
</xs:complexType>
<xs:complexType name="getCaseIdResponse">
<xs:sequence>
<xs:element maxOccurs="unbounded" name="sampleClass" type="tns:sampleClass"/>
</xs:sequence>
</xs:complexType>
<xs:complexType name="sampleClass">
<xs:sequence>
<xs:element maxOccurs="1" name="caseid" type="xs:string"/>
<xs:element maxOccurs="1" name="dummy" type="xs:string"/>
</xs:sequence>
</xs:complexType>
</xs:schema>
</wsdl:types>
<wsdl:message name="getCaseIdResponse">
<wsdl:part name="parameters" element="tns:getCaseIdResponse">
</wsdl:part>
</wsdl:message>
<wsdl:message name="getCaseId">
<wsdl:part name="parameters" element="tns:getCaseId">
</wsdl:part>
</wsdl:message>
<wsdl:portType name="TestClassInt">
<wsdl:operation name="getCaseId">
  <wsdl:input name="getCaseId" message="tns:getCaseId">
</wsdl:input>
  <wsdl:output name="getCaseIdResponse" message="tns:getCaseIdResponse">
</wsdl:output>
</wsdl:operation>
</wsdl:portType>
<wsdl:binding name="TestClassImplServiceSoapBinding" type="tns:TestClassInt">
<soap:binding style="document" transport="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/http"/>
<wsdl:operation name="getCaseId">
  <soap:operation soapAction="" style="document"/>
  <wsdl:input name="getCaseId">
    <soap:body use="literal"/>
  </wsdl:input>
  <wsdl:output name="getCaseIdResponse">
    <soap:body use="literal"/>
  </wsdl:output>
</wsdl:operation>
</wsdl:binding>
<wsdl:service name="TestClassImplService">
<wsdl:port name="TestClassImplPort" binding="tns:TestClassImplServiceSoapBinding">
  <soap:address location="http://localhost:8080/rc_ccb/TestClass"/>
</wsdl:port>
</wsdl:service>
</wsdl:definitions>
```

When given a SOAP request I'm getting the cast exception
**[Lcom.org.ccb.test.SampleClass; cannot be cast to com.org.ccb.test.SampleClass**

For getting an array of object from a web service, the following is the WSDL definition right?

```
<xs:complexType name="getCaseIdResponse">  
<xs:sequence>  
<xs:element maxOccurs="unbounded" name="sampleClass" type="tns:sampleClass"/>  
</xs:sequence>  
</xs:complexType>  
<xs:complexType name="sampleClass">  
<xs:sequence>  
<xs:element maxOccurs="1" name="caseid" type="xs:string"/>  
<xs:element maxOccurs="1" name="dummy" type="xs:string"/>  
</xs:sequence>  
</xs:complexType>
```

Server : JBoss eap 5.1

Any idea?

Stack Trace

```
14:31:46,743 WARNING [PhaseInterceptorChain] Interceptor for {http://test.ccb.org.com  /}TestClassImplService#{http://test.ccb.org.com/}getCaseId has thrown exception, unwinding now
org.apache.cxf.interceptor.Fault: [Lcom.org.ccb.test.SampleClass; cannot be cast to   com.org.ccb.test.SampleClass
at   org.apache.cxf.jaxws.interceptors.WrapperClassOutInterceptor.handleMessage(WrapperClassOutInterceptor.java:119)
at  org.apache.cxf.phase.PhaseInterceptorChain.doIntercept(PhaseInterceptorChain.java:243)
at org.apache.cxf.interceptor.OutgoingChainInterceptor.handleMessage(OutgoingChainInterceptor.java:76)
at org.apache.cxf.phase.PhaseInterceptorChain.doIntercept(PhaseInterceptorChain.java:243)
at org.apache.cxf.transport.ChainInitiationObserver.onMessage(ChainInitiationObserver.java:109)
at org.apache.cxf.transport.servlet.ServletDestination.invoke(ServletDestination.java:98)
at org.apache.cxf.transport.servlet.ServletController.invokeDestination(ServletController.java:406)
at org.jboss.wsf.stack.cxf.ServletControllerExt.invoke(ServletControllerExt.java:173)
at org.jboss.wsf.stack.cxf.RequestHandlerImpl.handleHttpRequest(RequestHandlerImpl.java:61)
at org.jboss.wsf.stack.cxf.CXFServletExt.invoke(CXFServletExt.java:163)
at org.apache.cxf.transport.servlet.AbstractHTTPServlet.handleRequest(AbstractHTTPServlet.java:179)
at org.apache.cxf.transport.servlet.AbstractHTTPServlet.doPost(AbstractHTTPServlet.java:103)
at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:637)
at org.apache.cxf.transport.servlet.AbstractHTTPServlet.service(AbstractHTTPServlet.java:159)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:290)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
at org.jboss.web.tomcat.filters.ReplyHeaderFilter.doFilter(ReplyHeaderFilter.java:96)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:235)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:235)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:191)
at org.jboss.web.tomcat.security.SecurityAssociationValve.invoke(SecurityAssociationValve.java:183)
at org.jboss.web.tomcat.security.JaccContextValve.invoke(JaccContextValve.java:95)
at org.jboss.web.tomcat.security.SecurityContextEstablishmentValve.process(SecurityContextEstablishmentValve.java:126)
at org.jboss.web.tomcat.security.SecurityContextEstablishmentValve.invoke(SecurityContextEstablishmentValve.java:70)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:127)
at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:102)
at org.jboss.web.tomcat.service.jca.CachedConnectionValve.invoke(CachedConnectionValve.java:158)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:109)
at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:330)
at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.process(Http11Processor.java:829)
at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Protocol$Http11ConnectionHandler.process(Http11Protocol.java:598)
at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$Worker.run(JIoEndpoint.java:451)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:662)
  Caused by: java.lang.ClassCastException: [Lcom.org.ccb.test.SampleClass; cannot be cast to com.org.ccb.test.SampleClass
at   com.org.ccb.test.jaxws.GetCaseIdResponse_WrapperTypeHelper1.createWrapperObject(Unknown Source)
at  org.apache.cxf.jaxws.interceptors.WrapperClassOutInterceptor.handleMessage(WrapperClassOutInterceptor.java:103)
... 33 more
```

** A major EDIT ** The Create Web Service wizard generated the esdl file but it did not contain maxOccurs="unbounded" , so i manually added , saved and restarted thought that it would ve changed, but found that wsdl isn't changing and it's retaining the old one, so it should be the problem! Couldn't find why the wsdl file isn't changing!

Comment: please post the complete stack-trace.

Comment: " Caused by: java.lang.ClassCastException: [Lcom.org.ccb.test.SampleClass; cannot be cast to com.org.ccb.test.SampleClass"

The L indicates that the original object is an array. What the stack trace is telling you is "I can't cast an array of SampleClass to an instance of SampleClass".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since its a bottom up service editing the wsdl was futile, hence I generated java skeleton classes from the wsdl (using JBoss Studio) and wrote my business in the implementation class. Now the service is working fine. Anyways I've no idea why `maxOccurs="unbounded"` wasn't generated automatically when the wsdl was generated from java classes at first. Thanks for the replies guys `@gkzmin @mhan @dan`

Answer (score 0):

I think that WSDL file generated by JBoss is wrong and following code

```
<xs:complexType name="getCaseId">
<xs:sequence>
<xs:element minOccurs="0" name="arg0" type="xs:string"/>
</xs:sequence>
</xs:complexType>
```

should look like this

```
<xs:complexType name="getCaseId">
<xs:sequence>
<xs:element minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded" name="arg0" type="xs:string"/>
</xs:sequence>
</xs:complexType>
```

Default `maxOccurs` attribute value is 1 and your array of `SimpleClass` becomes just a single instance of `SingleClass` which lead to class cast error (trying to cast array to instance).

I have no experience with JBoss studio but I can propose you to use some collection instead of array - maybe JBoss can handle collections better then arrays. Also you can try JAX-WS.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, but adding maxOccurs for getCaseId will allow us to input more values, the problem is with soap response( getCaseIdResponse ) not request.Anyways I made the change still the same error

Comment: Ooops, I am wrong. It seems that you have this error on a server side? Not the client side? Can you call you web service using `SOAP UI`, for example?

Comment: Yes you're right, this is a server side thing. Yeah i tried calling using Soap UI and promptly got the fault string response 
[Lcom.org.ccb.test.SampleClass; cannot be cast to com.org.ccb.test.SampleClass

Answer (score 0):

You need to understand a bit advance concepts.

http://weblogs.java.net/blog/kohsuke/archive/2005/04/xmladapter_in_j.html

http://blog.bdoughan.com/2011/06/using-jaxbs-xmlaccessortype-to.html

http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/5/tutorial/doc/bnazf.html

How I do this, is to get a class that will represent my table/entity. Then I have a wrapper class for the list_of_entities; which is the return from the web service. So, in total:

1. Entity class with the required annotations
2. Wrapper class with the required annotations
3. Web service with the required   annotations

I have provided a sample for each of these below, which **MIGHT NOT RUN**. They are just to give you an understanding.

```
//*********************** 1. your Object/Structure/table record you want to return

//since you'll like to send the object across thus it should be serializable
import java.io.Serializable;

//The following two imports are specific to your case. Read about them
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlElement;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlType;

//The code related to the following classes is just to give you a taster of the JPA side of it
import javax.persistence.Table;
import javax.persistence.Column;
import javax.persistence.Id;
import javax.persistence.Entity;


/**
 *  The class that will be the Type of your list, I have used it as an entity too for the JPA Layer
 *
 */
@XmlType(namespace = "myNamespace")

@Entity
@Table(name="MY_TABLE"
    ,schema="MY_DB_SCHEMA"
)

public class SampleClass implements Serializable {

/**
 * 
 */
private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
protected String caseid;
protected String dummy;
/**
 * @return the dummy
 */
@XmlElement(namespace = "myNamespace")
@Column(name="TYPE", nullable=true, length=225) 
public String getDummy() {
    return dummy;
}
/**
 * @return the caseid
 */
@Id
@Column(name="TYPE", nullable=false, length=225)


@XmlElement(namespace = "myNamespace")

public String getCaseid() {
    return caseid;
}
/**
 * @param caseid the caseid to set
 */
public void setCaseid(String caseid) {
    this.caseid = caseid;
}
/**
 * @param dummy the dummy to set
 */
public void setDummy(String dummy) {
    this.dummy = dummy;
}
```

}

//************************* 2. The  object wrapper class ****************************

```
// This file was generated by the JavaTM Architecture for XML Binding(JAXB) Reference Implementation, v2.1-b02-fcs 
// See <a href="http://java.sun.com/xml/jaxb">http://java.sun.com/xml/jaxb</a> 
// Any modifications to this file will be lost upon recompilation of the source schema. 
// Generated on: 2009.02.12 at 12:55:08 PM GMT 
//
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlAccessType;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlAccessorType;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlElement;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlType;

import YOURPACKAGE.SampleClass;

/**
 * Wrapper class for List, makes it possible for JAXB to marshal/unmarshal java.util.List.
 * 
 * @param <T>
 *          Generic List
 */
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
@XmlType(name = "myListType", propOrder = { "listReturn" })
public class ExampleList {

  /**
   * instructing JAXB about the xml element and the name to use in the resulting xml structure.
   */
  @XmlElement(name = "sampleClass")
  protected List<SampleClass> listReturn;

  public ExampleList() {
    listReturn = new ArrayList<SampleClass>();
  }

  /**
   * @param local_list
   *          a generic list
   */
  public ExampleList(final List<SampleClass> local_list) {
    listReturn = local_list;
  }

  public List<SampleClass> getList() {
    return listReturn;
  }

}
```

//*********************************

//******************** 3. The web service ************************

```
import javax.ejb.Stateless;
import javax.jws.WebMethod;
import javax.jws.WebParam;
import javax.jws.WebResult;
import javax.jws.WebService;
import javax.persistence.EntityManager;
import javax.persistence.PersistenceContext;
import javax.persistence.Query;

import org.apache.commons.logging.Log;
import org.apache.commons.logging.LogFactory;



@Stateless(name = "myEJB")
@WebService(serviceName = "myService", targetNamespace = "mynamespace", name = "myServicePT", portName = "myServicePort")
public class ServiceImpl implements ServiceLocal {

  @SuppressWarnings("unused")
  private final Log log = LogFactory.getLog(ServiceImpl.class);

  @PersistenceContext(name = "MyContext")
  private EntityManager em;


  @WebMethod(operationName = "listAll")
  @WebResult(name = "myList", targetNamespace = "mynamespace")
  public ExampleList listAll() throws EastException {
    try {
      Query query = em.createNamedQuery("myQueryToGetMyListFromDB");
      return new ExampleList(query.getResultList());
    }
    catch (Exception e) {
      log.error("Error in retrieving  list", e);

    }
  }



}
```

//*************** 3.1 web service local interface****************

```
import javax.ejb.Local;

@Local
public interface ServiceLocal {
    ExampleList listAll();
}
```

//**********************************************

Comment: Thanks for the reply, the solution seems to be a bit complex, I've to do some reading before posting doubts about your solution. But one question, without using all the XML annotations can't we do it in a simpler way like I did ? I mean, according to the materials available on the net What I had done is correct :( Please let me know if you can correct my code. Thanks again for spending your time answering me.

Comment: I never said that there is only one way of doing this :) But I must say that the result of my experience with web services and returning collections of objects, the only way I could get it working is the one I explained above. And I did say that you need a bit of reading. By the way, all that you need to do is to try the code above. I have given you all the structure. All the best